# Proof that if $a \mid b \Rightarrow |a| \le |b| $

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\text{let } a,b, c \in \Bbb Z \text{ such that } |a| > |b| \land a\mid b \text{ then, by definition, } a \mid b \Rightarrow b = ac \Rightarrow |b| = |ac| \text{ but } |a| > |b| \Rightarrow |ac| > |b|$
This give us an absurd , therefore $a\mid b \Rightarrow |a| \le |b|$

My question is: this is correct or there is another way to prove it?

Comment: This is correct, although the same principles could be applied in a more elegant manner; say, since $1\leq |c|$ we have $|a|\leq|c||a| = |ca| = |b|$.

Comment: @JonathanY. It would be good if you made that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PeterTamaroff suggests, let me reiterate my comment above:

Assuming $b\neq 0$ (otherwise for all $a\neq 0$ we *do* have $a\mid b$ but $|b|=0<|a|$), one has $|c|\geq 1$, and using that observation your argument is correct.

However, the same principle perhaps could be better articulated as follows:
$$1\leq |c| \Rightarrow |a| = 1\cdot |a| \leq |c|\cdot |a| = |ca| = |b|.$$

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Jonathan!